# Creating a file from a docker container

Tags: python, docker

Wondering how to create a file from inside a docker container.

For example in [this](https://github.com/jbruhn91/example_container) project I aim to create a text file. I get confirmation that the process is done, however, there's no txt file.

```
import logging
import os

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - [%(processName)s - %(threadName)s] %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", level=os.getenv('LOGLEVEL', 'INFO'))  

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)                     

f= open("example.txt","w+")
for i in range(10):
     f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
f.close() 
logger.info(f'Successfully created text file.')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The file will be created *inside* the container.

Comment: Where are you expecting / wanting the file to be created? What docker command are you using to run the container?

Answer (score 2):

The most effective way to share files between a host and a container running on it, is to use volume mounts. It's convenient to keep such volumes distinct.

For argument's sake:

1. Assuming you're in your project's root, `mkdir ./data` to create a directory at the same level as your `./src` folder.
2. Change your code (to prove the point) to `open("/aha/example.txt","w+")`. **NB** Yes, `/aha` not `/data`... keep reading.
3. Run the container and mount the host's (!) `./data` into the container as `./aha`: `docker run --interactive --tty --volume=${PWD}/data:/aha ...`. **NB** This mounts the host's `${PWD}/data` into the container as a directory `/aha`. IIRC you **must** use `${PWD}` to provide an absolute path
4. Once the Python code completes, the container will have a file called `/aha/example.txt` and your host (!) should include a file called `${PWD}/data/example.txt`

Comment: thx! Regarding point 3.: If I execute the command (docker run -- ...) from the command line inside the container I get :


"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker run --help'.

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container

Comment: do I write this in the dockerfile?

Comment: I don't know your container image name etc. and so the `...` needs you to fill in the values that you've been using to run the container. You'll need to add the `--volume=...` part.